# Changing behavior of the loop twice in one page

Tags: loop

I'm trying to set up a [wordpress blog](http://mosaic.ws/itb). I have one loop with featured posts, that pulls from the 'Featured' category and displays a slider of prominent posts.

Below that, I have the regular feed of posts. The regular feed works great, but the featured posts only show posts from wherever the bottom loop happens to be. Example, if I am on page one of the main feed, the top slider will only show posts with the category featured that are also on page one.

How can I make my slider loop pull from ALL Featured category posts?

EDIT: Added code, below:

```
<?php
/** Homepage file */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="rotator-wrapper">
<div class="featured-rotator">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?><ul>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( in_category('featured') ): ?>
                <li class="post">
                    <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                    <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true)): ?>
                    <span class="author">By <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php the_content(__("Continue reading &raquo;")); ?>
                </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul><?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content-wrapper">
    <h2 class="recent">Recent Reviews</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>   
    <ol>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li class="post">
            <article class="post-excerpt">
                <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="post-meta">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true)): ?>
                        <span class="author">By <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!--post-meta-->
                <?php the_content(__("Continue reading &raquo;")); ?>
            </article>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ol>

<nav class="oldernewer cf">
            <div class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div><!--.newer-->
            <div class="older"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries ') ?></div><!--.older-->
</nav><!--.oldernewer-->

    <?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts to display</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can ya paste the code for the featured slider post loop?

Comment: Please add all relevant code and information to your question. It is impossible to help you without seeing your code

Comment: You don't need the first loop, all you need is a slider which pulls your posts and includes settings which enable you to determine which posts featured images are displayed. Choose a new slider.

Comment: @TomHarrigan: added.

Comment: @BradDalton: I'm not using a plugin slider, I'm building my own using Unslider.

Comment: Then its a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new WP_Query for the slider posts.

```
<div class="featured-rotator">
    <?php $slide_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=featured' );
          if ( $slide_query->have_posts() ): ?><ul>
        <?php while ( $slide_query->have_posts() ) : $slide_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="post">
                    <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                    <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true)): ?>
                    <span class="author">By <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php the_content(__("Continue reading &raquo;")); ?>
                </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul><?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I found the codex docs on Wp_query but I couldn't get it to work on my own. Looks like my difference was what I was setting the query to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @authorandrew sure thing, glad it helped :)